# Scraping image, url, description from page

Tags: python, selenium, web-scraping, webdriver, phantomjs

I am trying to get image and video url from https://www.google.com/trends/home/all/IN

Here is the code:

```
driver = webdriver.PhantomJS('/usr/local/bin/phantomjs')
driver.set_window_size(1124, 850)
driver.get("https://www.google.com/trends/home/all/IN")
trend = {}
def getGooglerends():
    try:
    #Does this line makes any sense
        #element = WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(lambda driver: driver.find_elements_by_class_name('md-list-block ng-scope'))
        for s in driver.find_elements_by_class_name('md-list-block ng-scope'):
            print s.find_element_by_tag_name('img').get_attribute('src')
            print s.find_element_by_tag_name('img').get_attribute('alt')
            print s.find_elements_by_class_name('image-wrapper ng-scope').get_attribute('href')
    except:
        getNDTVTrends()
getGooglerends()
```

which gives

```
WebDriverException: Message: {"errorMessage":"Compound class names not permitted","request":{"headers":{"Accept":"application/json","Accept-Encoding":"identity","Connection":"close","Content-Length":"111","Content-Type":"application/json;charset=UTF-8","Host":"127.0.0.1:57213","User-Agent":"Python-urllib/2.7"},"httpVersion":"1.1","method":"POST","post":"{\"using\": \"class name\", \"sessionId\": \"648251c0-1cc7-11e5-bf1c-4ff79ddbdce4\", \"value\": \"md-list-block ng-scope\"}","url":"/elements","urlParsed":{"anchor":"","query":"","file":"elements","directory":"/","path":"/elements","relative":"/elements","port":"","host":"","password":"","user":"","userInfo":"","authority":"","protocol":"","source":"/elements","queryKey":{},"chunks":["elements"]},"urlOriginal":"/session/648251c0-1cc7-11e5-bf1c-4ff79ddbdce4/elements"}}
Screenshot: available via screen
```

Any suggestion for this error?

Answer (score 1):

> Compound class names not permitted

It basically means, that you can not have spaces in your class name. You need to switch to another selector, be that css, xpath or something like that.

Not really sure what you are trying to select, but for example following xpath selects a list of items containing that class:

```
//div[@class="homepage-trending-stories generic-container ng-scope"]/md-list[@class="md-list-block ng-scope"]
```

Comment: I am trying to get image link, descrption and article link from https://www.google.com/trends/home/all/IN page. Can you please help